# SSL Certificate change in Apache (Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name)

Tags: apache2, ssl-certificate

An SSL certificate expired on one of my servers and I ordered a new one from godaddy.
But if i replace the server.crt , the chain certificate and the server.key (the key used to generate the csr file) end up getting the ERROR

> Could not reliably determine the
>   server's fully qualified domain name

Note :

1. I have not made any changes in any configuration files.
2. I simply replaced the old certificates and key with the new one.I checked the key 
   andcertificate matched.
3. I am using Apache 2.2 on Windows 2003 server edition. I am restarting the server 
   after the change.
4. The server starts up fine if I revert back to the old certificates.

What could be the problem,I dont know how SSL certificates could result in this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the combination of 
1. server.crt
2. server.key (the private key used for generating the .csr used in creating the certificate.
3. ca.crt (the chain certificate)

I verified the private key issued using this article http://helpdesk.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064 , But I was not using the chain certificate. However the error in Apache was really ambiguous which led to further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and, at the end of the file, add:

```
servername myserver
```

place your server name in place of myserver.

also check this file:

/etc/hosts

make sure it matches your hostname. also make sure the fully qualified domain name is listed first. i.e.:

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

Comment: It did not work.I m working on windows and made the change in 
"C:\Prg Files\system32\drives\etc\hosts"
But there is one thing which dont understand is that why the apache starts correctly which the same server setting with the old certificates,but not the new olds.

Comment: I am getting this error whenever i start the apache service 

"The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX for ServerName"

but when i checked the ipaddress of the machine it was XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY..I dont get the error when I use the old security certificates.Is it possible that in any way the SSL certificates are associated with ip addresses.

Comment: Did you check your hosts file for entry of ipaddress Server is complaining ? 
Also Certificate should be attached to site name, It should not be attached to ipaddress. This could be problem in your case. You can Check details about certificate using "keytool" utility provided by JDK.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley did you find some solution to your problem ?

Comment: opening the certificate shows that the certificate has been issued to the correct domain..No I didnt find the solution.